# Dynamic label truncated on a spark button

Tags: apache-flex, button, air, adobe, flex-spark

I've got a spark button on a screen, and I'm updating the label dynamically using actionscript like so:

```
discount.label = this.data.SelectedDiscount.discount + "%";
```

The problem is that the new label text is truncated, even though there is room for it.

Initially the label in the button is blank:

[image: Black button label]

Then after I change the label with the code above it looks like this, when it should say "30 %":

[image: Truncated text]

However, if I then click the button it updates the display and renders it correctly:

[image: Correct rendering of the label]

I've tried all the various invalidate and validate methods, playing with the button width and more, all to no avail. If the initial label is wider, with a value like "-------" then it works ok, but unfortunately a string of whitespace doesn't do the trick. I don't really want a string of "0%" or "00%" for usability reasons so is there any easy way to get this working properly?

Preferably I'd like to avoid having to fake a mouse click just to achieve this.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Something must be off in your skin class. Can you show us some code?

Comment: discount is an instance of the Button class, correct?  Have you tried invalidatingSize() on the labelDisplay skin part of the Button? ( http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Button.html#SkinPartSummary ).  A runnable sample demonstrating the problem would help here.

Comment: Discount is a button in the mxml like so: "<s:Button id="discount" label="" width="12%"/>" — I should have mentioned that this is inside an item renderer.

Comment: Can you show your itemRenderer code?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @www.Flextras.com's guidance, I got this working by calling the `invalidateSize()` method on the button's skin rather than on the button itself, i.e.:

```
discount.skin.invalidateSize();
```

Comment: Interesting.  I wonder if calling invalidateSkinState() on the button would have had the same affect.

Comment: Just tried that out of interest, again didn't update the label until I clicked on it!